# I´m trying to add sound to my pong program with the play sound module on vscode but i cant import the module

Tags: python, python-3.x

here´s what i wrote to import it

import playsound

it just says this

(module) playsound
"playsound" is not accessedPylance
Import "playsound" could not be resolved from sourcePylance(reportMissingModuleSource)

Comment: What is your playsound module ? Is it a library module or is it one of your source code local modules ? Please provide enough details to make your problem understandable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.